# POST is not working instead of GET

Tags: php, post, get

The following code works for $_GET but not for $_POST.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
{
    $sql_query="DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_GET['delete_id'];
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
    header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edt_id(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Sure to edit ?'))
        {
            window.location.href='edit_data.php?edit_id='+id;
        }
    }
    function delete_id(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Sure to Delete ?'))
        {
            window.location.href='index.php?delete_id='+id;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="body">
    <div id="content">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5"><a href="add_data.php">add data here.</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>City Name</th>
                <th colspan="2">Operations</th>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $sql_query="SELECT * FROM users";
            $result_set=mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_set))
            {   ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="b_edit.png" align="EDIT" /></a></td>
                    <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img src="b_drop.png" align="DELETE" /></a></td>
                </tr>
        <?php
            } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the isset value and query to post instead of get. but when then the data delete button of data table not works. After changing the get method in isset and query and refreshing the page the row is being deleted. What is the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because these lines

```
window.location.href='edit_data.php?edit_id='+id;
```

Will generate a querystring on the URL which is passed to PHP in the `$_GET` array and not in the `$_POST` array.

If you want to use POST, you will have to use a `<form>` in your HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want using method POST,
you must be using `ajax post` or using `<form method="post">` .

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href='index.php?delete_id='+id;
```

and

```
entewindow.location.href='edit_data.php?edit_id='+id;
```

Are both $_GET, to do $_POST, use `<form action="#" method="post">` with the buttons inside of them. Then that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href='index.php?delete_id='+id;
```

This line always pass value by $_GET array. If you want to use $_POST method you should use ajax or form submit.